# Access derived class having base class object

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

This is my problem:

```
class A {
public:
   int foo;
   void setFoo(val) { foo = val; }
};

class B1 : public A {
public:
   void foo();
}

class B2 : public A {
public:
   void bar();
}

int main()
{
   A obj;
   switch(t) // some menu
   {
   case '1':
      obj.setFoo(something);
   case '2':
      obj.foo();
   case '3':
      obj.bar();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Switch is in a while loop - this is some kind of a menu. 1st case runs first.

The problems are cases 2 and 3. obj is the base class' instance, so I can't access these methods.

How can I solve this?

Creating two different objects for both derived classes does not work as I'd have to use setFoo() method on both of them, and well, it won't be the same attribute anymore.

Comment: What do you think `obj.foo()` would do, even if it did compile.  `obj` is of type `A`, so it can't be B1 or B2 and there is no inheritance to be done.  Could you be more clear about what `obj` really is?  Perhaps you actually have `A *obj = ` ?

Comment: Declare all those methods in base as virtual, and make `obj` an `A *` instead of object because if you assign a derived class object to base class you would be slicing the derived class attributes.

Comment: Besides what was already said, the class B1 isn't even valid because it uses a name for a function that is already used for an attribute in its base class.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare this functions in the base class as virtual or at lwast declare them in the base class.